# How should I setup the Wing IDE for use with IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, wing-ide

Here is a screen where I should point the Wing IDE to my python files. I am using IronPython.

[image]

Am I assuming correctly that textbox one gets filled with ipy.exe ? (proper path provided)

What should be in the rest of the boxes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about your question in particular; however few weeks ago, Michael Foord published a guide for using WingIde with IronPython.
You can find it here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/wing-how-to.shtml

Answer (score 0):

- Wing IDE at the moment doesn't allow the debug mode with IronPython. You need to link the IDE to the CPython install. (Michael Foord words in the article http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/wing-how-to.shtml][1](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/wing-how-to.shtml)).
- Wing IDE wouldn't run the shell while pointing at Python 3.1. I am unsure whether that is something I have done wrong or that the incompabilities aren't sorted out yet.

I have installed CPython implementation from Python download site.[Python download](http://python.org/download/)
I have set the Python executable path to the python.exe that gets installed to your Python Install directory. 
I have modified the enviroment variables and added the Python directory to the PATH variable.